# Uncaught TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

## Preview.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function...

I am trying to send the captured image on clicking a button with className='preview_footer' .I am getting this when I hit the button.
Here is the code for Preview.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './Preview.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { resetCameraImage, selectCameraImage } from './features/cameraSlice';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import TextFieldsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/TextFields';
import CreateIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Create';
import NoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Note';
import MusicNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MusicNote';
import AttachFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AttachFile';
import CropIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Crop';
import TimerIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Timer';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { db, storage } from './firebase';
import {uploadString, ref,getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { collection, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';


function Preview() {
  const cameraImage = useSelector(selectCameraImage);
  const navigate = useNavigate() ;
  const dispatch=useDispatch();

  useEffect (() => {
    if(!cameraImage){
      navigate("/", { replace: true }) //navigate(to, { state }).
    }
  }, [cameraImage, navigate]); // useEffect dependencies

  const closPreview = () => {
      dispatch(resetCameraImage());
  }

  const sendPost =() => {
    const id=uuidv4();
    const storageRef=ref(storage,`posts/${id}`);
    const uploadTask= uploadString(storageRef,cameraImage,"data_url");
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',null,
    (error) => {
        //ERROR function
        console.log(error);
    }, 
    () => { 
      // When Upload Completes (Complete Function)
      storageRef
      .ref('posts')
      .child(id)
      .getDownloadURL(storageRef)
      .then((url) => {
        collection(db,'posts').add({
          imageUrl : url,
          username : 'ABC',
          read:false,
          //profilePic,
          timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
        });
        navigate('/chats',{replace:true});
      });
    } );
  }

  return (
    <div className='preview'>
      <CloseIcon onClick={closPreview} className='preview_close'/>
      <div className='preview_toolbarRight'>
       <TextFieldsIcon/>
       <CreateIcon/>
       <NoteIcon/>
       <MusicNoteIcon/>
       <AttachFileIcon/>
       <CropIcon/>
       <TimerIcon/>
      </div>
      <img src={cameraImage} alt='' />
      <div onClick={sendPost} className='preview_footer'>
        <h2> Send To</h2>
        <SendIcon fontSize='small' className='preview_sendIcon'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Preview;
```

I tried changing the imports and the code based on firebase V9 Javascript format yet same error.

Comment: `uploadString` returns with a `Promise<UploadResult>`. You have to handle it accordingly.

Comment: I first implemented storageRef.putString in place of uploadString but it gave me that putString is not a function. And about handling promise can you please elaborate I'm new to this .

Comment: Okay I implemented .then(snapshot) and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you came up with your answer? Using the `.then(snapshot)`